# Wordpress create taxonomy in twentyseventeen child theme

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

i create a new wordpress theme using twentyseventeen theme and also created its child theme and activated it. Now i need to register taxonomy, i used the following code but does not showing anything. I copied it from wordpress official site. I am not getting where is mistake.

```
$labels = array(
    'name'              => _x( 'Genres', 'taxonomy general name', 'textdomain' ),
    'singular_name'     => _x( 'Genre', 'taxonomy singular name', 'textdomain' ),
    'search_items'      => __( 'Search Genres', 'textdomain' ),
    'all_items'         => __( 'All Genres', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Genre', 'textdomain' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Genre:', 'textdomain' ),
    'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Genre', 'textdomain' ),
    'update_item'       => __( 'Update Genre', 'textdomain' ),
    'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Genre', 'textdomain' ),
    'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Genre Name', 'textdomain' ),
    'menu_name'         => __( 'Genre', 'textdomain' ),
);

$args = array(
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
);

register_taxonomy( 'genre', array( 'book' ), $args );
```

Comment: Where did you add that code?

Comment: i added this code in functions.php in child theme, i also tried in main theme functions.php but failed. Nothing showing in wp dashboard.

Comment: Have you used add_action to call it when WordPress fires the `init` action?

Comment: I also tried in separate function in and also use `init` action